# how can I merge 2 arrays on each element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hello please I request your help, how can I merge 2 arrays? I leave the array examples.

Arrays will have the same number of elements.

```js
    var array1 = [
    {   a:1, b:2, c:3   },
    {   a:1, b:2, c:3   },
    ];
    var array2 = [
    {   d:4, e:5    },
    {   d:4, e:5    },
    ];
```

And this would be the result i need to get.

I try with map but i couldn't

```js
    var result =  [
    {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5},
    {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5}
    ];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you try this yourself first before posting here. Questions asking for code will most likely be closed rather than answered.

Comment: Use the `map()` method to loop over one of the arrays. The callback function receives the array index, which you can use to acccess the corresponding element of the other array. Then you can merge the two objects to produce the result element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the arrays and merge by mapping the objects at same index.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }],
    array2 = [{ d: 4, e: 5 }, { d: 4, e: 5 }],
    merged = [array1, array2].reduce((a, b) => a.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, ...b[i] })));

console.log(merged);
```